# Issue with drawparallels argument in Basemap

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap

This seems like it should be an easy fix but I can't get it to work. I would like 40°N to display in the attached plot, but setting the labels argument in drawparallels to [1,0,1,1] isn't doing the trick. That should plot the parallels lables where they intersect the left, top and bottom of the plot according to the documentation. I would also like for 0° to once again show up in the bottom right corner. Any idea of how I can fix those 2 issues?

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset as NetCDFFile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import addcyclic
nc = NetCDFFile('C:/myfile.nc')
lat = nc.variables['lat'][:]
lon = nc.variables['lon'][:]
time = nc.variables['time'][:]
olr = nc.variables['olr'][:]
olr,lon = addcyclic(olr,lon)
map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=0.,llcrnrlat=-40.,urcrnrlon=360.,urcrnrlat=40.,resolution='l')
lons,lats = np.meshgrid(lon,lat)
x,y = map(lons,lats)
levels = np.arange(-19.5,20.0,0.5)
levels = levels[levels!=0]
ticks = np.arange(-20.0,20.0,4.0)
cs = map.contourf(x,y,olr[0],levels, cmap='bwr')
cbar = plt.colorbar(cs, orientation='horizontal', cmap='bwr', spacing='proportional', ticks=ticks)
cbar.set_label('Outgoing Longwave Radiation Anomalies $\mathregular{(W/m^2)}$')
map.drawcoastlines()
map.drawparallels(np.arange(-40,40,20),labels=[1,0,1,1], linewidth=0.5, fontsize=7)
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(0,360,40),labels=[1,1,0,1], linewidth=0.5, fontsize=7)
```

[image: Plot showing issues with labels]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of the question is easy. In order for the label to show up, you have to actually draw the parallel, but `np.arange(-40,40,20)` does not include `40`. So, if you change that statement to `np.arange(-40,41,20)` your `40N` label will show up.

The second part should in principle be solvable in the same way, but Basemap apparently uses the modulo of the longitudes to compute the position of the labels, so just using `np.arange(0,361,40)` when drawing the meridians will result in two `0` labels on top of each other. However, we can capture the labels that `drawmeridians` generates and manually change the position of the second `0` label. The labels are stored in a dictionary, so they are easy to deal with. To compute the x position of the last label, I compute the difference in x-position between the first and the second label, multiply that with the amount of meridians to be drawn (360/40) and add the x-position of the first label.

Here the complete example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=0.,llcrnrlat=-40.,urcrnrlon=360.,urcrnrlat=40.,resolution='l')

map.drawcoastlines()
yticks = map.drawparallels(
    np.arange(-40,41,20),labels=[1,0,1,1], linewidth=0.5, fontsize=7
)
xticks = map.drawmeridians(
    np.arange(0,361,40),labels=[1,1,0,1], linewidth=0.5, fontsize=7
)


first_pos = xticks[0][1][0].get_position()
second_pos = xticks[40][1][0].get_position()
last_x = first_pos[0]+(second_pos[0]-first_pos[0])*360/40
xticks[360][1][0].set_position((last_x,first_pos[1]))

plt.show()
```

Here the resulting plot:

[image: result of the above code]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This solved both of my issues. Can you tell me why np.arange(-40,40,20) captures -40 but not 40?

Comment: `numpy.arange` works basically the same way as the standard `range`: if you pass three values, the first one is the starting value, the middle one is the stop value, and the last value is the increment. `arange` produces values by adding the increment value to the original starting value as long as the resulting number is *smaller* than the stop value. It's probably taking a bit of getting used to, but that's the way it is defined.